# Allied assistance of the Soviets during WW2

Tags: world-war-two, soviet-union

Why did the Allies share Ultra intel with the Soviets about the imminent Battle of Kursk, and why did the US support the USSR through "Lend Lease".

I understand that at the time it wasn't very clear that the Soviets would be 'victorious', however given that the Allies were already considering the post-war situation, wouldn't it have been in the Allied interest if other allied nations were supported more, or the USSR was even denied intel, since then post war the allies would have gained more territory throughout mainland Europe, and at the most extreme case, would have invaded Russia to displace the Nazis? 
Would more resources given to the UK, Netherlands, even be helpful at all? Could the Iberian's have been bribed through economically to join the war?

Comment: Please cite all assertions.

Comment: The USA and USSR were allies during the war so they shared intel?

Comment: The Spanish *were* being bribed to stay *out* of the war.

Comment: There is a proverb that WWII was won by American industry, British courage, and Soviet blood. A gross oversimplification, like all similar sayings, but the Americans found it effective to spend their money to make the Soviet soldiers more effective.

Comment: @o.m This proverb is completely incorrect. It implies Soviets did not have any industry, while in fact all the Soviet population, who were not fighting on the frontlines, was involved in military industry. Not to mention the implication that only Brits were courageous.

Comment: @vpekar, I said it was a *gross oversimplification*. Among the Allies, the Americans provided an over-average share of the industrial production, and the Soviets provided an over-average share of the casualties. *Of course* much of that was because the Soviet leadership was inept, and because the Americans happened to live out of bomber range.

Comment: if i could, i would vote to unhold this question :D

Comment: @o.m How can people who sacrificed their lives lack courage, while those who didn't were "more courageous on average"??? How can this be even an oversimplification? So the Soviets lost the most lives because their leadership was inept, not because the other Allies preferred to spend their money instead of lives? Curious. Also, While US production can be described as over-average, Soviet casualties cannot be described as "over-average" - they were dozens of times more than those of US.

Answer (score 6):

FDR had a deep concern that Stalin would make a separate peace with Hitler.  That was his motivation in pushing an unconditional surrender agreement among the Allies.  For his part, Stalin demanded a second front effort from his partners in the war.  Operation Torch in North Africa was the best the unprepared U.S. could muster.  The Soviets continued to do the heavy lifting against the Nazis.  After Stalingrad perhaps even Hitler recognized that the war was lost to him. But there was much heavy fighting before this happened.   So, succinctly, FDR wanted (needed) Stalin to pay the big end of the price of victory.  Meanwhile the Allies provided Stalin with material and other assistance to keep him in the battle.